# Stuck in log-in loop, Ubuntu randomly crashes, Windows still boots first

Tags: dual-boot, password, encryption, crash

I'd really appreciate it if someone could shed some light on 3 problems of mine:

I tried to reset my forgotten account password using the "standard way" in [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LostPassword). However, when I enter the new password at log-in, the screen goes black and just asks me for my password again. Small googling has told me that this is because you're not supposed to use the above method when the home drive is encrypted. I do still have the unwrapped key that I was given at installation, however, so how can I use it to fix this and have a working password again?

Second problem is very vague: about every other day, Ubuntu will crash without warning as if I took the battery straight out of the laptop. Any thoughts?

Last is hopefully easy to fix; the pre-installed Windows 8.1 always boots first, even with ubuntu listed above it in UEFI settings. I boot into Ubuntu by holding shift as I restart Windows.

Thanks!!

EDIT: My laptop is a [Lenovo Flex 2 15D](http://www.staples.ca/en/Lenovo-59424917-Flex-2-Notebook-156-8GB-1TB/product_1148177_2-CA_1_20001)

Answer (score 0):

Your second issue sounds like a hardware problem.  If you reply with the brand/model of your laptop I'll try to look it up for you to see if it is a known problem.  Are you using a cooling stand?

Comment: Sorry, just edited that into the end of my question, here it is: http://www.staples.ca/en/Lenovo-59424917-Flex-2-Notebook-156-8GB-1TB/product_1148177_2-CA_1_20001

No cooling stand, but I've only had the laptop for about 2 months. I can't have had anything overheat in that time, could I?

Comment: I had a friend in college who killed two laptops in a month operating it on her sofa.  I had to explain to her that the air intake was on the bottom of the laptop, and that the sofa was blocking the airflow killing the laptops.

I sincerely doubt you are actually operating it on a soft surface like your lap or a sofa, but if you are, I should tell you, yes, that can cause it.